# Select all textboxes in a document using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, textbox

I would like to select all the contents of the text-boxes when a user clicks on it. But, since my document contains almost 5 text-boxes, instead of giving each text-box an ID selector or `onfocus` attribute, I would like to select all the text-boxes.

For example: `var x = document.getElementsByTagName("p");`

The above code selects all the paragraphs in a document. So, I need a similar code for all textboxes. I have tried replacing `input` and `input[type=text]` Nothing worked.

Comment: Input should work - show your html

Comment: <input type="text" value="Some text" id="input1" />

Comment: @Gowtham can you setup a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Try this out:-

http://jsfiddle.net/adiioo7/zvgHx/

## JS:

```
var x = document.getElementsByTagName("INPUT");
var y = [];
var cnt2 = 0;
for (var cnt = 0; cnt < x.length; cnt++) {
    if (x[cnt].type == "text") y.push(x[cnt]);
}

alert("Total number of text inputs: " + y.length);
```

## HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="input1" value="input1"></input>
<input type="text" id="input2" value="input2"></input>
<input type="text" id="input3" value="input3"></input>
<input type="text" id="input4" value="input4"></input>
<input type="text" id="input5" value="input5"></input>
```

**So, array `y` will hold all inputs with type as text.**

Comment: I'm asking to select all textboxes for applying css styles through JS... Can I do that with this technique?

Comment: thumbs up - that helped :)

Answer (score -3):

Use jQuery: `$('input[type=text]')` That will do the trick.

http://jquery.com/

Comment: He is not using jQuery nor his question is tagged with jquery.